# Face size using image processing

Tags: image-processing, face

I'm trying to find out some measures which could allow me to quantify (approximatively) the size of a face (small, medium, large). What measures can I considerer ? (for example, distance between the nose and mouth...). 
Can you bring some references if exist? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to find small, medium, large faces, you can measure facial landmarks, OpenCV will help you to overcome this problem.

Please see:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/03/facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python/

Another option might be to detect faces with drawing circles. Then find circumference of circle.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check it

Comment: I have checked the tutorial which is interesting. However, after the landmarks have been computer (I've obtained their coordinates), how can I compute the real size from the image (since I don't know the real size of the face) ? 
I mean even if I can compute the euclidean  distance between tow landmaks, this distance will not reflet the real distance between the associated regions on the real face.